# Storing price as Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have made the decision to store prices as an Integer but I am having difficulties with this.

The user will of course enter the price in pounds and pence and I want to store as pence but what's the best way of doing this.

What I have tried so far is a `before_save` in my model:

```
def convert_price
  self.price = self.price * 100
end
```

but there are two problems to this - firstly I am using a transaction in my controller (to make sure something else I am doing is ok too before saving) so it seems to multiply by the 100 twice! The second issue is that if a user enters 56.85 for example, looking in the terminal it will say the input is 56 because it will typecast as an Int before doing anything else.

I don't want to use the Money gem as I feel it's overkill - hoping for a nice and simple solution.

Comment: Can you check it without using transaction..? I think it's causing duplicate multiplication. I am guessing this from your question point of view. Please make it clear

Comment: Without the transaction I have just the second issue - that of typecasting

Comment: What does your transaction call in the controller look like? Go ahead and update the question to include that code. It's probably fine, but you never know...

Comment: Also, maybe try an `after_validation` callback instead of `before_save`? Maybe Rails does typecasting before the `before_save` callbacks? (Just a guess, so I could be wrong, hence why this is a comment and not an answer.)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the decimal separator. If no decimal separator was found in the amount, no decimals were provided, so then just multiply by 100.

```
def convert_price
  if /\./.match(price)
    price.gsub!(/\./, '')
  else
    price *= 100
  end
end
```

To prevent that the price is converted multiple times, you could create a custom setter for price:

```
def price=(val)
  if /\./.match(val)
    val.gsub!(/\./, '')
  else
    val *= 100
  end
  self.price = val.to_i
end
```

Although I'm not sure this will work. It will fail if you set the same price multiple times.

#### Final words

Perhaps the best solution is to use the `decimal` type to store the price.

Comment: this doesn't really tackle the issues though! Firstly, the Transaction issue will still apply. Secondly, the typecasting will still have taken affect

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer but it might not be what you are looking for.